# Import values at windows form from keyboard as user

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like to set every time i run my program values for 3 variables(for example x-y-z_ from keyboard.I know how to do it at console application but i am a little confused with win form because i use it for a first time.Could someone give me some help?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean command-line arguments?

Comment: For example when i run the program i would like a window to opens and users can import the values from keyboard.*Maybe with toolbox

Comment: Ok. So, your program has a main form, but you would like another form to open (a modal window?) that allows the user to input values. When that modal closes, the data will be used by the main form/application?

Comment: No i use only one form.When it ends i would like just to save the values.

Comment: What will you do with the values? Save them to a database?

Comment: Transfer them to a console application to another program that i have already combine the solutions with the win form.I am trying to develop an Interface to my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something like writing three variables (it will be strings) to three textboxes, just make form with these components (I hope you are using visual studio), then you can get the text from them with something like:
`string mystring1 = textbox1.text;
string mystring2 = textbox1.text;
string mystring3 = textbox1.text;`

and then you will have access to these three variables

Comment: Yes of course i use Visual Studio.Thank you a lot it works fine. :)

Comment: Your welcome :-) can you just accept my answer? I want better reputation :D